Azure Pipelines conditional insertion for release branch
i want to create pipeline that will show prod stage only for release/ branches. I developed yaml like this:
trigger:
- main

pr:
- main

stages:
- template: templates/infra-terraform-deploy.yml@templates
  parameters:
    # parameters

- template: templates/infra-terraform-deploy.yml@templates
  parameters:
    # parameters

- ${{ if startsWith( variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'refs/heads/release' ) }}: 
  - template: templates/infra-terraform-deploy.yml@templates
    parameters:
      # parameters


But unfortunately, last stage is always not present in my pipeline.
How to construct yaml pipeline in Azure Devops that will show last stage only for branches that starts with release?

Try
- ${{ if startsWith( variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'release' ) }}: 


or
- ${{ if startsWith( variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release' ) }}: 

reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

First condition doesn't work.

Hi @Rui, Thanks, But I have just re-test, both works at my side.

it will work for releases/1, release/1, release123456 - that's not what the OP is asking.

You need an extra / in both conditions, actually.

Given a Git repo branch refs/heads/main:

$(Build.SourceBranch) will return refs/heads/main
$(Build.SourceBranchName) will return main

So instead of:
- ${{ if startsWith( variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'refs/heads/release' ) }}: 
  - template: templates/infra-terraform-deploy.yml@templates
    parameters:
      # parameters

Try:
- ${{ if startsWith( variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/' ) }}: 
  - template: templates/infra-terraform-deploy.yml@templates
    parameters:
      # parameters

See Predefined variables

To show prod stage only for release/ branches, you should use
- ${{ if startsWith( variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release/' ) }}: 
Take branch release/test1 for example, output the value of Build.SourceBranchName and Build.SourceBranch:

The value of Build.SourceBranchName is test1 instead of release/test1. So that it will not work if you use - ${{ if startsWith( variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'release' ) }}: 
If you use - ${{ if startsWith( variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release' ) }}:, stage prod will also show if the source branch is something like refs/heads/releasetest.
